# SQL - merge two queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the two below queries, the first query returns a list of `externalId`.

[image]

```
select e.externalId 
from data_entity db 
inner join assign_entity a on db.fk_assign = a.assignmentId 
inner join exercise_entity e on a.fk_exercice = e.externalId;
```

The second query returns an `internalId` of each `externalId` returned by the first query:

```
select me.internal_id 
from entity me 
inner join entity_roles r on me.externalid = r.entity_externalid 
where r.roles = 'c9237a21-f6da-4ebe-81b0-ddecd51da86b';
```

How can I merge the two queries in a single query to return for each externalId its internalId like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what is required I think. Since there is no fiddle/data present, I can not test it.

```
with external as
(select e.externalId as externalId  from data_entity db 
inner join assign_entity a on db.fk_assign = a.assignmentId 
inner join exercise_entity e on a.fk_exercice = e.externalId)
select distinct e.externalId, me.internal_id from entity me 
inner join entity_roles r on me.externalid = r.entity_externalid 
inner join external e on r.roles = e.externalId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select me.internal_id, me.externalId 
from entity me 
inner join entity_roles r on me.externalid = r.entity_externalid 
WHERE r.roles = 'c9237a21-f6da-4ebe-81b0-ddecd51da86b'
and exists (
select * from data_entity db 
inner join assign_entity a on db.fk_assign = a.assignmentId 
inner join exercise_entity e on a.fk_exercice = e.externalId
where e.externalId = me.externalId
);
```

Probably this query is simpler than what it is now, but based only on your pictures and queries this would do.

PS: Next time, please provide a good sample of your data tables. Pictures do not help much to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Without some data or a fiddle it is difficult to help, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT me.internal_id,
       me.externalid
FROM   entity me
       INNER JOIN entity_roles r
               ON me.externalid = r.entity_externalid
WHERE  r.roles = 'c9237a21-f6da-4ebe-81b0-ddecd51da86b'
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   data_entity db
                          INNER JOIN exercise_entity e
                                  ON a.fk_exercice = e.externalid
                          INNER JOIN assign_entity a
                                  ON db.fk_assign = a.assignmentid
                   WHERE  me.externalid = e.externalid);
```

Comment: How is this different from the query provided long ago?